# Does it exsist an additive Merging strategy?

Tags: git, version-control

I have the branch master where I have the file Prova.c:

```
int main()
{
     printf("Ciao mondo");
}
```

and a branch named c++version where i have modified tha same file Prova.c like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
     cout<<"Ciao mondo"<<endl;
}
```

On the master I do the command (lated add and commit in both the branches):

```
git merge c++version
```

and I get in the master this file Prova.c :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Ciao mondo"<<endl; \\I don't like this
}
```

I don't like the result. I wanted both printf and cout but I have the cout alone. What merging strategy (or other solution) could I adopte?
Or in extreme case how can I impose that git ask me every time to resolve all conflicts?

Comment: Show the results of `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all`. Not sure where you got your notions of what branching does but I'm guessing `c++version` was branched off `master`, and when git went to merge it, none of the changes conflicted with any `master` changes so it took all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a situation where you have one branch which has a region of unmodified code (`master`) and one branch which has been modified (`c++version`). When you have this situation and you merge in the modified branch, Git pulls all of those changes in, because the result of a merge is the sum of all changes from both sides.

In this case, part of the change that's being made is to delete the `printf` line and insert a `cout` line. The additions and deletions are both a part of that change.

A conflict only results when the same code is changed on both sides. If only one side is changed, then a merge includes that change. That's just how merging works. Git does provide strategies to take only one side or the other, but that won't help you in this case, since what you want is not to delete any lines, and Git doesn't offer a strategy that does that.

Moreover, such a strategy wouldn't be very useful, because it isn't obvious in what order you would want the lines added (is it before or after the existing lines?) and thus every such merge would have to result in a conflict so you could fix that.

This is one of those situations where the merge succeeds syntactically, but results in semantically undesirable changes. You can amend the merge with `git commit --amend` to change the result of the merge, but beyond that, there really isn't much that Git provides for this situation.

Comment: Thanks now I understand the git merging strategy altought it doesn't exist an "additive" method.